# Finding the Img src beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to scrape the image src through this HTML code could anyone help me. I want to get the link for each image but it doesn't seem to work. At the moment it will display the image link. I tried adding the src=True that doesn't seem to fix it. It will print none. I've looked on this platform for any idea and I'm able to solve the problem maybe I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

The code

```
import requests, lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.carsireland.ie/used-cars/bmw")
content = url.content
pri = lxml.html.fromstring(url.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find_all("article", {"class": "listing"})


for row in rows:
    img1 = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__images--main"}, 'img')
    img2 = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__images--small"}, 'img')
    img3 = row.find('div', {"class": "listing__images--small"}, 'img')


    print(img2)
```

HTML CODE

```
<article about="/2739145" class="listing" role="article">
    <div class="listing__images--main">
        <img alt="BMW 316 2007" loading="lazy" src="https://c0.carsie.ie/d43864c90df075c94489ddbe4ca5ffe9f6541083f25076da0bf4218f7baa03f6.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="listing__images--small">
        <img alt="BMW 316 2007" loading="lazy" src="https://c0.carsie.ie/d43864c90df075c94489ddbe4ca5ffe92d2f6814d6ed7098b46525ba484aca27.jpg" />
        <img alt="BMW 316 2007" loading="lazy" src="https://c0.carsie.ie/d43864c90df075c94489ddbe4ca5ffe905915c7415aa1ce328840dfdbfd7d9cd.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="listing__details listing__details--desktop">
        <div class="listing__details-location">
            Meath
        </div>
        <div class="listing__details-vehicle">
            <h2>BMW 316</h2>
            <p>316I ES Z3SQ 4DR E90 SALOON N45 1.6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="listing__details-data">
            <div class="listing__details-data-year">
                <p>2007</p>
            </div>
            <div class="listing__details-data-mileage">
                309 km
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="listing__details-pricing">
            €900
            <div class="listing__details-private-seller">Private</div>
        </div>
        <div class="listing__details-color">
            <span class="" style="background-color: black;"></span>
            <p>BLACK</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go from the parent article tag level then loop that and extract all img

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.carsireland.ie/used-cars/bmw')
soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
listings = soup.select('article')

for listing in listings:
    print([i['src'] for i in listing.select('img')])
```

---

EDIT:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.carsireland.ie/used-cars/bmw')
soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
listings = soup.select('article')

for listing in listings:
    large = listing.select_one('.listing__images--main img')['src']
    small_top = listing.select_one('.listing__images--small img')['src']
    small_btm = listing.select_one('.listing__images--small img + img')['src']
    print(large, small_top, small_btm)
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn what is in print() into a variable?

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to find a specific image as each car has 3 images associated with it. If you look at the there are 2 divs tag(1 with an img link and 2 with one as well). Just wondering if I could have 3 variables so I can scrape it.

Comment: Thank you very much It's working perfectly much appreciated.